# How to use @Rule in Selenium Junit to fail a test

Tags: testing, selenium, junit, try-catch, junit-rule

I've got the following test which I have put a try catch around so it fails if actual value does not equal expected value:

```
    try{
        Assert.assertEquals(ExpectedCount, ActualCount);
    }catch (Throwable t){
         System.out.println ("Actual value is not equal to expected value");
    }
```

Whenever I run this test it passes. However if expected=actual no message is printed, which is correct. If they are not equal then the message i printed. So the test logic is valid.

However the Juint test still passes.

I have been trying the incorporate the following but cannot get it to work:

(Added this at public level in the class of the test)

```
@Rule

Public ErrorCollected errCollector = new ErrorCollector();
```

Added:

```
errCollector.addError(t);
```

Under

```
System.out.println ("Actual value is not equal to expected value");
```

I am getting the error back "`Rule cannot be resolved to a type`" It does not give me any option to import.

I've been trying to find out how use the `@Rule` method to make the test to fail, but cannot figure it out.

Comment: You catch the exception that junit throws to make the test fail. Therefore the test passes.

Comment: I am running them as part of a suite, so I need to know that it has failed.

Comment: check your junit version @Rule was introduced in junit4.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @oers says, the reason you can't find Rule is probably because your version of JUnit is too old. Try a later version, > 4.7.

The easiest solution to your problem is just to rethrow the exception that you're catching:

```
try {
    Assert.assertEquals(ExpectedCount, ActualCount);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    System.out.println ("Actual value is not equal to expected value");
    throw t;
}
```

but you'll need to add throws Throwable to your test method. You have another alternative, to add a description to your assert:

```
Assert.assertEquals("Actual value is not equal to expected value", ExpectedCount, ActualCount);
```